# ¿Cómo cambiar el valor de un atributo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito  que el valor "valor_a_cabiar",

```
 src="web.com/id/valor_a_cabiar"
```

se remplace por otro tomando en cuenta que la id de la publicación es diferente para cada pagina:

Ejemplo:

```
    web.com/1245?valor_a_cabiar
    web.com/2541?valor_a_cabiar
    web.com/3416?valor_a_cabiar
```

por lo que hay que remplazar solo una parte del atributo `src` algo asi;

```html
<iframe class="video" src="web.com/id?valor_a_cabiar"></iframe>

<!-- Nuevo -->

<iframe class="video" src="web.com/id?Nuevo_valor"></iframe>
```

Comment: Stacksnippet sólo debe usarse cuando el código se puede usar en la publicación. Por otro lado, la pregunta no incluye lo buscado/investigado como se require en [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes buscar el caracter '?' en el src, y a partir de ahí poner el nuevo

```js
var ifr = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
var srcifr = ifr[0].getAttribute("src");
var newValue = "valor_cambiado";
var i = srcifr.indexOf("?");
if(i>-1){
 i = (i+1);
 var changestr = srcifr.substring(i,srcifr.length);
 var newVal = srcifr.substring(0,i) + newValue;
 ifr[0].setAttribute("src", newVal);
}
```

```html
<iframe class="video" src="web.com/id?valor_a_cabiar"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente ponle id al `iframe` por ejemplo

```
<iframe id="video-frame" class="video" src="web.com/id?valor_a_cabiar"></iframe>
```

luego en Javascript

```
document.getElementById('video-frame').setAttribute('src', newUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola debes usar esta linea:

```
document.getElementById("imagenid").src="../valorAcambiar/nombre.png";
```

o si usas jQuery ...

```
jQuery("img")[0].src = "../valorAcambiar/nombre.png";
```

Por ejemplo... Si haces inspeccionar el elemento, veras que en el src pone `"hola"`, cuando hagas click cambiará el valor a `"adios.png"`:

```js
function cambiartexto(){
  document.getElementById("imagen1").src = "adios.png";
}

document.addEventListener("click",cambiartexto);
```

```html
<img id="imagen1" src="hola" />
```

Comment: alguna razón porque los tags en tu(s) respuestas?

Comment: @aldanux Hago uso de jQuery y javascript sobre elementos html, es mas, me falta el tag de jQuery.

Comment: no entiendo... es innecesario de agregar en las respuestas tags... hasta molesta (el popup)

Comment: no entiendo bro..
Si me puede ayudar con el ejemplo completo

Comment: La pregunta no menciona jQuery por lo que no tiene sentido incluirlo, a menos que explicaras el motivo por el que lo recomiendas.